# crontab truncates file path

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, cron

I try to run the following command:

```
crontab -u root /root/iss/current/node/bin/installers/nl_brandless_selector_full_hd/nl_brandless_selector_full_hd_cron_file
```

But I got an error like this:

```
/root/iss/current/node/bin/installers/nl_brandless_selector_full_hd/nl_brandless_selector_full_hd_c: No such file or directory
```

The file exists there, but it seems, that crontab truncates the last few characters of the file path, as it seems from the error message. Is this a bug?

Op: Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

**EDIT:**

Here is an "ls" output, so it can be seen, that the file exists and readable (and I was root, when I tried to run the crontab command):

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1707 Aug 28 00:22 /root/iss/current/node/bin/installers/nl_brandless_selector_full_hd/nl_brandless_selector_full_hd_cron_file
```

**EDIT2:** If I rename the file to nl_brandless_cron, it perfectly works, so now I'm sure, that this really is a nasty BUG

Comment: A 100 characters seems an odd number if it's the maximum length of the path+filename. Does the crontab command work if you make `/root/iss/current/node/bin/installers/nl_brandless_selector_full_hd` your working directory first and then simply run `crontab -u root nl_brandless_selector_full_hd_cron_file` ?

Comment: Yes it works if I "cd" into the directory

Comment: I know it doesn't really answer your question by why not just use `cat file | crontab -u root` instead?  crontab will accept data in stdin if no filename is provided.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first try simplifying the length using a symbolic link.

I am also wondering if the error message ONLY is being truncated and indeed the access to the file is problematic.

Comment: if I use a simbolic link, it works, so I think it really truncates the path, not just the error message